# How to clear a specific field upon changing the date in django?

Tags: python, django, ajax, database, cron

I'm working on a website that has to do with user entering data to fields of a table. There is (input type=date) in top of the page. I want the user to enter values daily. but I want to save that data in the database according to that day and if the user change the date, I want to clear some fields for that day for a new fresh entry.

I also don't know if there should be a datefield in model or not?? If so, would I have to populate the database with lots of dates? and if it reach the last date, I have to populate it again and so on??

How I go about doing this?

I tried looking for a solution but couldn't find one that seems good. I found I could use crontab in django or scheduler but I don't think this is the optimum solution.

Comment: Is the date in a field the user enters?  Or are you trying to detect when the system date changes?

Comment: detect ! but I have (input html field with date type) that will show different data for the user when changing to old date with Get request. That's the idea at least.

Comment: You can do a periodic task in your Javascript to detect if the current date is different from what it has stored.  Then you can send any unsent data, and clear out the form fields.  That avoids the problem of a user in a different timezone from your server.